# Why wont std::bind work with a std::filesystem::path and std::ostream?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, stdbind

I am currently trying to write a program that makes use of `std::bind` with a `std::filesystem::path` and `std::ostream`, both as references, as follows:

```
#include <functional>
#include <filesystem>
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>

struct Buggy{
    static void something(const std::filesystem::path &path, std::ostream &out);
    void bind();
};

void Buggy::bind(){
    auto function = std::bind(&Buggy::something, std::placeholders::_1, std::cout);
    function(std::filesystem::path("./"));
}

void Buggy::something(const std::filesystem::path &path, std::ostream &out){
    out << path.string() << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    Buggy buggy;
    buggy.bind();
}
```

I expect this code to simply output "`./`", but instead, it gives me [massive template errors.](https://pastebin.com/VnmPa959) Why is this? My use of `std::bind` looks correct to me. I am compiling with `g++ --std=c++17 bug4.cpp -o bug4 -lstdc++fs` on Linux.

I am unable to read the template errors because they are so intermixed with implementation details of this standard library. I have tried compiling with clang and gcc, both of which give similar errors. Searching via a search engine gives no useful results.

Comment: Your milage may vary, but I always found it a pain to work with `std::bind` and since we have lambdas I never used it again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parameters bound through `std::bind` are copied by default. `std::cout` is non-copyable. You need to use `std::ref`.

```
auto function = std::bind(&Buggy::something, std::placeholders::_1, std::ref(std::cout));
```

Personally, I'd avoid using `std::bind` and use a lambda expression instead.

```
auto function = [](auto&& path){ return Buggy::something(path, std::cout); };
```